# How can I display a base64-encoded image in Jetpack Compose without using external libs

Tags: android, base64, android-jetpack-compose, image-loading

I could convert the base64 string to `android.graphics.Bitmap` but from all I can find online, I still need coil or glide to display it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a `Bitmap` you can use the [**`.asImageBitmap()`** extension](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/graphics/package-summary#asimagebitmap) to get a Compose `ImageBitmap` object.

Then use it in an `Image` composable.

```
Image(
    bitmap = bitmap.asImageBitmap(),
    contentDescription = "contentDescription"
)
```

Comment: I use this solution and is currently giving me lagging effect on my LazyColumn. Any other idea?

Comment: Sounds like the bitmap is being decoded in the composable. You can make it lazy by setting it as a rememberable so it will only decode once.